# Preserve directory structures when optimizing js files with grunt + uglify

Tags: gruntjs, minify, uglifyjs, uglifyjs2

I'm using the grunt [Uglify plugin](https://npmjs.org/package/grunt-contrib-uglify) to minify the JS files.

The issue I'm having, is that I would like to keep the src directory structure in the dest directory as well.

example:

```
**src dir:**
js
 |- app1
    |- randomFile.js
    |- scripts
       |- file1.js
       |- file2.js
    |- libs
       |- file3.js
       |- file4.js

**destination dir:**
js
 |- app1
    |- randomFile-min.js
    |- scripts
       |- file1-min.js
       |- file2-min.js
    |- libs
       |- file3-min.js
       |- file4-min.js
```

the `-min` portion is is just a nice to have (could live with out that), but I'm really struggling to figure out how to preseve the directory structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

disregard, I found an answer in a different post: [how to config grunt.js to minify files separately](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13358680/how-to-config-grunt-js-to-minify-files-separately)

turns out my grunt-fu is just weak ;-)