# How to concatenate groups of scripts separately in Grunt?

Tags: javascript, gruntjs

I was looking into the possibility of building a webapp that conditionally loads groups of scripts based on the screen size and/or client of the user, because there may be some UX or client specific code that I might load based on this information.

I saw another question that showed how to have files minified separately ([see link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13358680/how-to-config-grunt-js-to-minify-files-separately)), but I wasn't sure if there was an option to take all scripts in group A, B, and C and minify them separately to groupA.min.js, groupB.min.js, and groupC.min.js. Is this possible?
Thanks,
- Daniel

Example:

```
uglify: {
  dist: {
    files: {
        'dist/shared.min.js': 'src/shared/*', //would recurse shared directory and concatenate/minify all JS in subdirectories
        'dist/desktop.min.js': 'src/platform/desktop/*',
        'dist/mobile.min.js': 'src/platform/mobile/*',
        'dist/ios.min.js': 'src/platform/ios/*',
        'dist/android.min.js': 'src/platform/android/*'
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Look at grunt multi-tasks at http://gruntjs.com/configuring-tasks. Maybe that's what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something along these lines should work according to the [**docs**](http://gruntjs.com/configuring-tasks#task-configuration-and-targets), which I've partly butchered:

```
grunt.initConfig({
  concat: {
    groupA: {
      // concat task "groupA" target options and files go here.
      dist: {
        // the files to concatenate
        src: ['src/groupA/*.js'],
        // the location of the resulting JS file
        dest: 'dist/groupA.concat.js'
      }
    },
    groupB: {
      // concat task "groupB" target options and files go here.
    },
  },
  uglify: {
    groupA: {
      // uglify task "groupA" target options and files go here.
    },
    groupB: {
      // uglify task "groupB" target options and files go here.
    },
  },
});
```

Then you can run specific task with grunt concat:groupA or grunt concat:groupB.

Comment: Thanks, I think you're right, so I'll mark it as the answer.